# Using Intersect with arcpy.GetParameterAsText() and ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, parameters, error-000732, intersect

I'm trying to use the intersect tool, with one of my inputs being from a get parameter as text. As I don't have an advanced licence I have to iterate through the list to run the intersect on each item in the list.

However, there is something about the input into the intersect analysis it doesnt like. I get the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "\DRBS-NAS01\ueec\GIS\100
> MT testing\BufferTest\Scripts\Intersection batch.py", line 37, in
>
> arcpy.Intersect_analysis(Des4, DirectAndIndirect + "\test2", "ALL")   File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 334, in
> Intersect
> raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset SOBLayer
> #;'\DRBS-NAS01\ueec\GIS\100 MT testing\BufferTest\Data\Designations\Ancient_Woodland_England.shp' #
> does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (Intersect).

```py
    import arcpy
    import os
    
    ## Working folders
    WorkingDir = os.getcwd()    ## To go up more directories: os.getcwd() 
    os.path.dirname(os.getcwd());  os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
    DesDir = WorkingDir + "\\Data\\Designations"
    OutputDir = WorkingDir + "\\Data\\Outputs"
    Interim = OutputDir + "\\Interim"
    DirectAndIndirect = OutputDir + "\\DirectAndIndirect"
    
    if not os.path.exists(DirectAndIndirect):
        os.makedirs(DirectAndIndirect)
    
    SiteOptions = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    SiteOptionsBuffers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    
    DesList1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
    DesList2 = DesList1.split(';')
    
    DesBufferList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
    
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(SiteOptionsBuffers, "SOBLayer")
    
    query = '"IndImpBuff" = {}'.format(DesBufferList)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("SOBLayer","NEW_SELECTION", query)
    
    Des4 = ["SOBLayer"]
    for Des1 in DesList2:
        Des2 = os.path.basename(Des1)
        Des4.append(Des1)
        arcpy.Intersect_analysis(Des4, DirectAndIndirect + "\\test2", "ALL")
```

Could someone suggest what the problem with the Intersect input is please?

Comment: Try creating variables for the inputs of the intersect and use print statements to see if they're what you expect. Or, since this is being run as a script tool, use AddMessage.

Comment: You can use arcpy.Exists to check if the datasets exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. It's led me to a solution. The AddMessage was showing that in the DesList2 it was listing the dataset as:

u"'\DRBS-NAS01\ueec\GIS\100 MT testing\BufferTest\Data\Designations\Ancient_Woodland_England.shp'"

A bit of digging, and for reasons I dont understand, changing my loop as follows got it working:

```
for Des1 in DesList2:
    Des2 = os.path.basename(Des1)
    Des6 = Des1[1:-1].encode()
    Des4.append(Des6)
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis(Des4, DirectAndIndirect + "\\test2", "ALL")
```